# Java JDK 32 bits vs 64 bits

Tags: 32bit-64bit, java

I am creating a quite simple application which reads and display text files and search through them.

I am asking myself if there is any interest for me to propose 32 and 64 bits version to the user.

Is the difference only in having access to more memory heap size with the 64 bit version or is there any other interest ?

Will a 32 bit compiled program work on a 64 bits JVM (I assume yes)

Comment: As long as your application is 100% pure Java there's not much difference except for the possible heap size.

Comment: Just remember that the 32 and 64 bit JRE's are separate installations, and most people only have the 32 bit one installed by default (even on 64 bit machines).

Comment: Thanx for your answers. As I expected, for pure Java this does not change anything (except for the heap size).

Comment: If you intend to package your Java program as an "application bundle" (meaning a self-contained .exe/.app/binary which includes your Java plus a full JRE), then selection between 32-bit and 64-bit is *definitely* in-scope, here. Nobody wants to have to install a JRE just to run your .jar file, and you may reach a (slightly) wider audience with a 32-bit bundled JRE than a 64-bit one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only differences between 32-bit and 64-bit builds of *any* program are the sizes of machine words, the amount of addressable memory, and the Operating System ABI in use. With Java, the language specification means that the differences in machine word size and OS ABI should not matter at all unless you're using native code as well. (Native code *must* be built to be the same as the word-size of the JVM that will load it; you can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit builds in the same process without very exotic coding indeed, and you shouldn't be doing that with Java about.)

Comment: The size of the native word can make a fundamental difference to C or C++ code, especially if badly or hackily written, but Java code will not see the difference at all.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. That's clear to my mind that in pure Java this will not change anything.

Comment: @HpTerm: In pure Java, all that changes is the amount of addressable memory (good) and the amount of memory per object (not so good). Neither is a change that will lead to problems you can see unless you're running close to the VM limits.

Comment: @Donald Even the amount per object will be basically the same because at least Hotspot already allocates on 8byte boundaries anyhow. And for heaps <= 32gb compressed Oops mean we don't use more memory per pointer

Comment: @Voo: Depends on the details. It's certainly normal to allocate on an 8-byte boundary, but fields within the object will probably be 4-byte aligned as the amount of waste would be too high otherwise; 8-byte alignment only really makes sense for `double` and `long`, and any kind of reference on 64-bit, and a lot of objects have many fields that are not of those types.

Comment: @Donal You confuse allocating objects on a specific boundary with the alignment of primitives inside them. For primitives we only want to avoid unaligned loads of the CPU and that's the same in both cases. The overhead of at most 7byte per object is negligible.

Comment: @Voo: No, I don't confuse the two. The real issue is that on 64-bit systems you have larger pointers than on 32-bit. That expands the required space for a _field_ of reference type from 4 bytes to 8 bytes (and it might also change the alignment requirements), which in turn increases the memory consumption of a great many classes. Lots of classes contain fields that refer to other objects. Every single one will pay the cost.

Comment: You can do tricks to pack the pointers down into fewer bytes, but that means that you're using computed values as reference types, which tends to disrupt memory prefetching (the prefetch can't be started until the computation finishes) and so clobbers performance. (All the CPU can see is that the shift instructions and the load instructions have a data dependency between them. Knowing that "it's OK you can prefetch with some smartness" is impractical at that level.) And yes, I did used to work with CPU engineers many years ago.

Comment: You're jumping from one topic to the next it seems to me. Yes we have to add a `lea` before every load from memory but really that's cheap - a cycle at most but I'm pretty sure we can fuse the ops there. And we can compute the address way before we actually want to access it. In practice I doubt that the overhead is noticeable - certainly not in case of a l1 miss.

Comment: @Voo: It's not as simple as that. It's not the lea, it's the fact that  there's a data dependency between the computation of the address to load from and the lea, which frustrates pipelining of access even to the cache as the CPU can't say what address to issue until the computation is done. And you pay that cost on _every single dereference_, which usually means multiple times in an inner loop. By contrast, a simple lea (or even one with a fixed offset) is simpler, and much more heavily optimized. It's also typically done on a value that wasn't created in the previous instruction.

Comment: Let's be clear, fancy bit stuffing is expensive. It's really expensive when addresses are involved precisely because it causes problems with instruction pipelining (it forces much of the CPU to halt and wait for the computation to become available). It's not that it has to be that way, but no popular CPU has specific instructions for the case (IIRC,AIUI) and it's not one that CPU designers optimize for. Full-width addresses are much faster because they're a case that _everyone_ optimizes (since it's used in masses of code).

Comment: Given the size of memories and caches now available, and the fact that pipelining is _critical_ for speed, I really don't think that anyone does that absurd packing. They certainly don't if they're aiming for the high end, where 32GB would not be described as a particularly large amount of physical memory to have. Heck, it won't be long before ordinary desktop systems commonly have more. But you don't have to take my word for it on the costs: go out and implement the two systems (in C probably) and compare for yourself.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty clear that there's a dependency between the lea and the lw (but then I'm pretty sure those are fused, in which case that's not true either), but frustrates pipelining? The only way that's possible is if the CPU can't do anything else until the word is loaded which is extremely unlikely (there's a reason modern CPUs have OoO execution) and even if, we'd stall the pipeline anyhow, now just a tinsy bit longer. In practice, pipeline stalls mostly happen if we miss to memory and in that case one cycle more or less is unimportant..

Comment: You seem to have a big misunderstanding how pipelining works these days. And you "really don't think that anyone does that absurd packing"? Maybe reading up about the topic we're discussing before claiming some extremely dubious things would help? CompressedOops are default on any Hotspot JVM since 6.24 or so and the performance hit is negligible in general. (Also note that at least on Intel the ROB was redesigned to allow 3 dependencies instead of 2 so that's not limiting either)

Answer (score 2):

The only times that have swung it for me is when there have been native libraries involved that have pushed it one way or the other. If you're just in Java land then realistically, unless you need >4GB of heap size, there's very little difference.

EDIT: The differences include things like it uses slightly more memory than 32 bit, significantly more if you're using a version before 6u23 and aren't using  `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`. There may also be a slight performance difference between the two, but again nothing huge.

Comment: You didn't say "no difference" but said "very little difference. Just for my knowledge assuming pure Java, was is this very little difference.